# Can not Add custom CSS JS to Django app AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, css, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using AWS elastic Beanstalk for deploying my Django app however I am not able to load CSS/JS files to my app.

http://django-env-1.ufcakifk9g.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/static/quiz/style.css

This is my path to css file.

It is loading successfully when I am running the server locally and the path is

http://localhost:8000/static/quiz/style.css

I have added 
STATIC_URL =  '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR ,'static/')

to my settings.py file.

Can you please tell where I am wrong and how to fix the issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Same issue, were you able to solve it?